# Problema con JComboBox

Tags: java, eclipse

Tengo el siguiente problema ,uso JComboBox con ningún item y tiene un `ActionListener`, los items se lo agrego desde otra class, el tema es que al agregar los item (los agrego con `JComboBox.addItem();`) me lo agrega y me acciona el `ActionListener`, como puedo agregar los items sin activar el `ActionListener`?

-la clase del JComboBox

```
package En_El_Traslado;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JComboBox_Fechas extends JPanel{
    public JComboBox_Fechas() {
//      TITULO
        TITULO_FECHA=new JLabel("Dia");
//      CREACION DEL JCOMBOBOx
        FECHAS_TRASLADO=new JComboBox<String>();
//      ACCION DEL JCOMBOBOX
        FECHAS_TRASLADO.addActionListener(new Accion_Dia());
//      AGREGAMOS TODOS 
        add(TITULO_FECHA);
        add(FECHAS_TRASLADO);
    }
    class Accion_Dia implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Bien");
        }
    }
    public static JComboBox<String> FECHAS_TRASLADO;
    public static JLabel TITULO_FECHA;
}
```

-aca donde se le llama-

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Menu extends JPanel{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       JButton Boton=new JButton("Dia Martes");
       Boton.addActionListener(new Action_Boton());
       add(boton);
}
class Action_Boton implements ActionListener{
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
   JComboBox_Fechas.FECHAS_TRASLADO.addItem("Martes");
```

Comment: Que tal, podrías anexar el código que estas realizando para poder apoyarte mejor

Comment: Cual es el comportamiento que buscas?

Comment: que no se active el ActionListener al agregar o eliminar un ítem ,yo uso para agregar JComboBox.addItem(); y para eliminarlo uso JComboBox.removeAllItems();